# Wordpress custom category.php - pagination link stuck on page 1

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm developing a custom Wordpress theme. Before this, the pagination link for page 2 shows a 404 error but I somehow managed to fix it but now, clicking page 2 doesn't do anything. It's stuck on page 1. This is my first time attempting to develop a custom theme from scratch. Help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my category.php

```
    <?php

get_header();

$currCat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'));
$cat_name = $currCat -> name;
$cat_id = get_cat_ID($cat_name);

$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1; 
$wp_query = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 6,
  'cat' => $cat_id,
  'paged' => $paged)); 

  $big = 999999999;  
    echo paginate_links(array(
          'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
           'format' => '/page/%#%',
           'current' => max(1, $paged),
           'prev_text' => __('Previous Page'),
           'next_text' => __('Next Page'),
           'show_all' => true,
           'total' => $query->max_num_pages   ));?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area container">
  <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

  <div class="post-category">
    <h2 class="post-category-title"><span class="post-category-title-m"><?php single_cat_title();?></span></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="post-items">
  <?php if ($wp_query-> have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ($wp_query -> have_posts() ) : $wp_query -> the_post(); ?>
    <div class="post-item">
      <div class="post-thumbnail"><?php the_post_thumbnail('single-thumbnail'); ?></div>
      <div class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
      <strong>
        <?php the_date( 'F j, Y','<div class="post-date">','</div>'); ?>
        <div class="post-excerpt"><?php the_excerpt();?></div>
      </strong>
    </div>
            <?php endwhile; 
          else :
            // No Post Found
  endif; ?>
  </div>
  <nav class="page_nav">
    <?php custom_pre_get_posts($wp_query); ?>
  </nav>
  <!-- <?php //wp_reset_postdata(); ?> -->
</div>
</div>

<?php get_footer();?>
```

And the function in my functions.php

```
function custom_pre_get_posts($query)
{   global $paged;
    $big = 999999999;  
    echo paginate_links(array(
        'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max(1, $paged),
        'prev_text' => __('Previous Page'),
        'next_text' => __('Next Page'),
        'show_all' => true,
        'total' => $query -> max_num_pages
    ));

    if ($query->is_main_query() && !$query->is_feed() && !is_admin() && is_category()) {
    $query->set('page_val', get_query_var('paged'));
    $query->set('paged', 0);
   }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts');
```